# How to retrieve folder files from Google Cloud using PHP client library?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I want to retrieve all files of a folder in Google Cloud Storage. I searched a lot but cannot found anything. I have tried this:

```
$bucket = $storageService->objects->get(DEFAULT_BUCKET,"myfolder/",array());
$getBucketMarkup = generateMarkup('Get Bucket', $bucket);

print_r($getBucketMarkup);
```

Comment: i have solved this problem

Comment: cool. if you provide your solution as answer to your question it can help other people who may face the very same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by putting two parameters of List Objects in array one Is delimiter and the second one is prefix

```
$bucket = $storageService->objects->listObjects(DEFAULT_BUCKET,array(
    "delimiter"=>"/",
    "prefix"=>$folder_name
    ));
```